# Password Validator in Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, fluentvalidation

How can I validate Password using Fluent Validation? **for example, using data annotation we can put this attribute [Password] for password property**, ***how to get the same result but using fluent validation???***

when I type in the box of password it shows black circles when I use data annotation, how to do the same but using fluent validation?

Comment: look it's javascript (jquey ) this kind of validation validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Equal Validator to check if the property is equal to the value of another property e.g.

```cs
RuleFor(customer => customer.Password)
    .Equal(customer => customer.PasswordConfirmation);
```

[Equal Validator Documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#equal-validator)

To create a field for password entry where the input is hidden use `type="password"` e.g.

```html
<input type="password" @asp-for="Model.Password">
```

[Input field documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password)

Comment: **I mean when we type in the box of password it shows black circles when I use data annotation how to do the same but using fluent validation**

Comment: The question asks if FluentVlidation can confirm the property type(password) not it's value. This doesnt answer the OP.